# Quote.class doesn't return the Quote type, but Account.class does. Why?

Tags: apex, sobject, type

I'm trying a library that acts like an object factory. It works with serialization, so it is possible to specify formula fields without DML, which is pretty handy with tests.

My issue is that I'm trying to write a class that requires the Quote type. The apex compiler throws me the following error when using `Quote.class`:

> Invalid field class for SObject Quote

But `Opportunity.class`, `Account.class` and even `QuoteLineItem.class` work just fine. Any idea why? Is it not possible to get the quote type? Or is there another way of doing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a variable named 'Quote' in your variable scope. Do not do this.

```
Quote quote = new Quote();
System.debug(quote.class); // compile-fail
```

It works if you avoid naming variables after class names:

```
Quote theQuote = new Quote();
System.debug(Quote.class); // outputs Quote
```

You can still refer to it correctly if you use the Schema namespace, though:

```
Quote quote = new Quote();
System.debug(schema.quote.class); // Outputs Quote
```

Comment: Are you a wizard!? Hahaha, that was it. There was a variable on the test class called "quote". Using the Schema namespace worked.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Let's just say that many of my answers to questions like this come from personal experience. 

Comment: Renato, sfdcfox is too modest : he *is* a wizard !